# Angularjs directive that depends on another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writting a custom directive to bind a html select element to an unordered list.

It works just fine with static select elements.

However, I couldn't make it work with dynamic selects. Is there a way to my directive retrieve the options generated by ng-options or ng-repeat directives?

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fjbyq/3/

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('taskFilterChoices', function() {
  return {
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="listToggleBox listType" data-ng-transclude><ul class="choicefilterList"><li data-ng-repeat="option in options"> <a href="" class="taskFilterLink" data-value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.text }}</a> </li> </ul> </div>',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var _select = element.find('select'),
          _selectOptions = [];

        _select.hide();
        _select.find('option').each(function(i, option) {
          var _optionObj = {
            value: option.value,
            text: option.innerText
          };
          _selectOptions.push(_optionObj);
        });
        scope.options = _selectOptions;
      }
  };
})

.directive('taskFilterLink', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $(element).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var _select = $(this).closest('.listToggleBox').find('select');
            _select.val($(this).data('value')).triggerHandler('change');
        });
      }
  };
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Looked at your fiddle...where does "operators" come from, in the dynamic select? It felt like something was missing.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.

You are right. I forgot to add the controller.

I updated the fiddle.

However it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: This is quite a challenging problem. ng-repeat and ng-options are terminal, so using priority to try and get something to run after them is no good. Plus your directive is on the parent element. You may have to create a directive to put on the select that $watches whatever you use for the repeat or options, and also you would have to pass that same thing into this directive's scope to update when the options/repeat changes. Perhaps it would be easier to just create a custom version of ng-repeat or ng-options that emits an event on rootscope, and listen for it in the other directive?